# Reactjs/Redux login form architecture

Tags: java, spring, forms, reactjs, redux

I am fairly new to redux and I am looking to integrate it in this clean build. I started the project from the facebook indicator, then ejected it to configure the webpack to handle scss.

// Current problems

1. When I try and start typing on the form - nothing happens - not sure if its because the store is broken?
2. When I submit there is an error on the handleSubmit -- I need to make a dummy service to "post" to. I will maybe need to support the backend developer with creating the Java Spring controllers - and responses. So what kind of dummy data would I send -- email and password -- and the response I would need back is an authentication token, user data? Once the user is logged in or if the user is already logged in - I would want them to then be exposed to the /home component -- so I am unsure how to then redirect the user properly. Also this Java service would be on a different port - so may need suggestions on how to bundle/webpack build the reactjs into the java spring web application properly.
3. So also when the user has logged in in a successful response - would then want to do future calls - maybe once on the home component to start drawing more information data from that user -- so how would I stash that to the redux store - do multiple calls etc..

This is the structure of the application. I've started to place my pages in the various components - most are basic reactjs components - but I've started to hook into redux and various antd components for the login form.

--

```
  my-app
    ├── build
    │   ├── static_
    │   ├── asset-manifest.json
    │   ├── favicon.ico
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── manifest.json
    │   └── service-worker.js
    ├── config_
    ├── node_modules_
    ├── public
    │   ├── favicon.ico
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── manifest.json
    ├── scripts_
    ├── src
    │   ├── components
    │   │    ├── About
    │   │    │    └── About.js
    │   │    ├── Account
    │   │    │    └── Account.js
    │   │    ├── Error
    │   │    │    └── Error.js
    │   │    ├── Footer
    │   │    │    └── Footer.js
    │   │    ├── Header
    │   │    │    └── Header.js
    │   │    ├── Home
    │   │    │    └── Home.js
    │   │    ├── Login
    │   │    │    ├── Login.js
    │   │    │    └── LoginForm.js
    │   │    ├── Privacy
    │   │    │    └── Privacy.js
    │   │    └── Terms
    │   │         └── Terms.js    
    │   ├── App.js
    │   ├── App.scss
    │   ├── App.test.js
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── index.scss
    │   ├── logo.svg
    │   ├── registerServiceWorker.js
    │   └── router.js
    │
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── package.json
    ├── README.md
    └── yarn.lock
```

--
So the workflow I want to create here.

// Land on the root of the application and see a Login form - if not logged in.

[image]

// On successful login authentication - go to the home page

[image]

So here is the current js structures

// index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

// App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.scss';

import Routes from './router'

// this is a class because it needs state
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Routes />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

// router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux'

// components
import Login from './components/Login/Login'

import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Account from './components/Account/Account'

import About from './components/About/About'
import Terms from './components/Terms/Terms'
import Privacy from './components/Privacy/Privacy'

import Error from './components/Error/Error'

import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

//const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(
const store = createStore(compose(
  typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
  )
)

// we can pass the lang files as props to the routes
// we should have a nested route inside service here to show the other services page

class Routes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div className='off-canvas-wrap' data-offcanvas>
            <div className='inner-wrap'>
              <Header transparent />
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/account' component={Account} />

                <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                <Route path='/terms' component={Terms} />
                <Route path='/privacy' component={Privacy} />

                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route path='/' component={Login} />
                <Route component={Error} />
              </Switch>
              <Footer transparent />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default Routes
```

// components/Home/Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import { render } from 'react-dom'
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

// this is a class because it needs state
class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Page">
        Home
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

// components/Login/Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import { render } from 'react-dom'
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

// components
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

// this is a class because it needs state
class Login extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  submit (values) {
    // creating the body of the request
    const body = {
      request: {
        email: 'email@email.com',
        password: '1234'
      }
    }
    // sending the object to the backend api
    fetch('/api/loginUser', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      header: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log('Response from fetch:', response)
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('An error has occurred -', err)
    })
    // setting the redux store to show the thank you page)
    // new code to store redux state with login authentication details?

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Page">
        <LoginForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

// components/Login/LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import { render } from 'react-dom'
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form'
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'antd'


const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Required'
  } else if (values.password.length < 2) {
    errors.password = 'Must be 2 characters or more'
  }
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required'
  } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
  }
  return errors
}

const renderField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, warning}}) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} style={{border: '1px solid #CCD0D5', marginTop: '10px', marginBottom: '3px'}} />
            {touched &&
            ((error && <span className='text--red text--font-size-14'>{error}</span>) ||
            (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
        </div>
    </div>
)

// this is a class because it needs state
class LoginForm extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit, submitting} = this.props
    return (
      <div className="Page">
        Login

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Row className='grid__row--offset--30'>
            <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={14} >
              <Field
                name='email'
                type='email'
                component={renderField}
                label='email'
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className='grid__row--offset--20'>
            <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={14} >
              <Field
                name='password'
                type='text'
                component={renderField}
                label='password'
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className='grid__row--offset--30'>
            <Col span={13}>
              <button type='submit' className='button success radius expand' disabled={submitting}>Login</button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const {object, string, func, bool} = React.PropTypes
renderField.propTypes = {
  input: object,
  label: string,
  type: string,
  meta: object
}

//export default LoginForm

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: func,
  submitting: bool,
  lang: object
}

// ==================================================================================================
// ==================================================================================================
//
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(LoginForm)
```

---

here is some parts of other code I have - that handles storing fetched data -- but I would welcome help glueing this to the form code I've got. I am not sure why this example relies on redux-thunk or middleware -- or what the various fetch functions do - if they are needed etc..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux' 
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import MapChart from './modules/mapChart/MapChart'
import './index.css'

function fetchPostsRequest(){
  return {
    type: "FETCH_REQUEST"
  }
}

function fetchPostsSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
    payload
  }
}

function fetchPostsError() {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_ERROR"
  }
}

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_REQUEST":
      return state;
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS": 
      return {...state, posts: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

function fetchPostsWithRedux() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchPostsRequest());
    return fetchPosts().then(([response, json]) =>{
      if(response.status === 200){
        dispatch(fetchPostsSuccess(json))
      }
      else{
        dispatch(fetchPostsError())
      }
    })
  }
}

function fetchPosts() {
  const URL = 'https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=52.268,0.543:52.794,0.238:52.130,0.478&date=2017-01';
  return fetch(URL, { method: 'GET'})
     .then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}

// this is how you'll get your icon links
// instead of a switch with loads of repetitive bytes
const iconMap = {
  'anti-social-behaviour':  'green-dot',
  'burglary':               'red-dot',
  'other-theft':            'pink-dot',
  'public-order':            'purple',
  'robbery':                 'yellow',
  'vehicle-crime':          'orange',
  'violent-crime':          'orange-dot',
  'other-crime':            'ltblue-dot',
  'criminal-damage-arson':  'yellow-dot',
  'drugs':                  'purple-dot',
  'shoplifting':            'blue-dot'
}

// this is a class because it needs state
class CrimeMap extends Component {
  state = {
    markers: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.props.fetchPostsWithRedux()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({markers: this.mapLayerData(nextProps.posts)});
  }

  // store only the data you want to pass as props to each Marker
  // instead of mapping it directly in MapChart every time it renders
  mapLayerData(markers) {
    // use a standard map function instead of $.each
    // destructuring saves time and repetition
    return markers.map(({ category, location }) => ({
      // use a template string and a simple map of icon names to get your icon uri
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+ iconMap[category] +'.png',
      label: category,
      name: category,
      position: {
        lat: location.latitude,
        lng: location.longitude
      }
    }))
  }

  render() {
    // there's only one layer, so render it directly
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <MapChart markers={this.state.markers} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    posts: state.posts
  }
}    

let Container = connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPostsWithRedux})(CrimeMap);

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Container/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Its also fine if you add these things in plunker/else

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN  - add these things in plunker?  else? - you mean something like a jsfiddle - not sure how to do that with a react/redux demo?

Comment: @TheOldCounty, these are good questions, but they are too broad. You are basically asking busy people to get involved in all aspects of this architecture and help you figure it out. Not going to happen as you can see. I would modify this to just ask help with the login flow or the authentication flow.

Comment: @Daniel - that was an issue - nearly 8 months ago. It was worthy of posting - if someone discussed it or proposed a solution none the less